# SPI MOSI line only hits 1.2V for speeds above 500kHz and below 4MHz (3.3V logic)

Tags: avr, spi, display, tft

I'm trying to drive a [ST7789](https://www.banggood.com/1_3-Inch-IPS-TFT-LCD-Display-240240-Color-HD-LCD-Screen-3_3V-ST7789-Driver-Module-p-1383404.html?rmmds=myorder&cur_warehouse=CN) TFT display ([datasheet)](https://www.rhydolabz.com/documents/33/ST7789.pdf) with an [ATTiny-416](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/40001913A.pdf), but for some reason SPI fails at speeds above 500kHz. So far I've had these results:

- 500kHz: pass
- 666kHz: fail
- 1MHz:   fail
- 2MHz:   fail
- 4MHz:   pass

The 4MHz is especially strange. Technically the AVR is operating out-of-spec there, since it runs 16MHz at 3.3V (max is 10MHz for 3.3V)

Here's my SPI routine:

```
void SPI_init(){
    //PORTMUX.CTRLB |= (PORTMUX_SPI0_ALTERNATE_gc);
    SPI0.CTRLB = SPI_SSD_bm | SPI_MODE_3_gc;
    SPI0.CTRLA =  SPI_MASTER_bm | 
                  SPI_PRESC_DIV4_gc |
                  SPI_ENABLE_bm;


    //SPI0.INTCTRL |= (SPI_IE_bm) | (SPI_RXCIE_bm);
    PORTA.DIRSET = (1<<1) | (1<<3);
    PORTA.DIRCLR = (1<<2);
    
    //PORTA.OUTCLR = (1<<1) | (1<<3);
    
    PORTA.PIN1CTRL |= (PORT_ISC_INPUT_DISABLE_gc);
    PORTA.PIN3CTRL |= (PORT_ISC_INPUT_DISABLE_gc);
}

uint8_t SPI_write(uint8_t data){
    SPI0.DATA = data;   //write dummy byte
    
    while(!(SPI0.INTFLAGS & SPI_IF_bm));
    return SPI0.DATA;
}
```

And what the oscope sees:

[image]
[image]

And a schematic:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fJVhQr.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Yellow trace looks like two signals trying to drive the same wire. Also, SCL/SDA are I2C. SCK and MOSI are SPI. Two different interfaces...

Comment: Yes, it does seem that way. The nomenclature is a translation error - the datasheet clears that up. Interestingly, 'SDA' (or MOSI-equivalent) has this as a pin description:
-When IM3: Low, SPI interface input/output pin. 
-When IM3: High, SPI interface input pin.

Comment: And where is IM3 in your implementation? MOSI is output only so you need "SDA" input only...

Comment: IM3 is not brought out externally - presumably it's connected Low, which would somewhat explain the problem (though why would it work at all then?)